# download image from Docker Hub and convert to gcr.io

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. I found an image (https://hub.docker.com/r/vanvalen/deepcell/). I want to use this image in a cluster where I need a corresponding gcr.io file.I am not sure how to do so and I would truly appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a project created on GCP and, container registry api is enabled for that project.

Note: you will also need to install docker-ce and gcloud-sdk on your machine, if you are using terminal/putty.

Step 1: first of all initiate your project (open terminal/putty and fire below mentioned commands give/provide required data) -

```
gcloud init
```

Step 2: initiate communication between gcr.io (This is something that will configure docker config.json file (location is => /root/.docker/config.json)) -

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Step 3: now use docker push to push the image in gcr repo (To check docker images fire, `docker images` command in terminal that will give you list of images available)-

```
docker push gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<TAG>
```

step 4: Now check the GCR repo, you will find your image there...

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank you so so much!

Comment: sorry for the subsequent question but what is the project ID? vanvalen/deepcell?

Comment: `PROJECT_ID`  is nothing but an ID of your newly created Project. When you create a new Project at that time Google cloud platform will create `PROJECT_ID` associated with that newly created Project for you (by-default your `PROJECT_NAME` will be your `PROJECT_ID`, you can change it, as per your requirement).

Comment: Thanks a ton! now that i have the image, how do i build it on google cloud?

Answer (score -1):

Step1: First of all spin up an instance (micro, small, standard - as per your requirement)

Step2: Install docker-ce on that instance (these steps are for ubuntu 16.04 machine):

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
apt-get install -y docker-ce
systemctl status docker
```

Step3: install gce on that instance (these steps are for ubuntu 16.04 machine):

```
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
wget https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/apt-transport-https/download
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Step4: Initialize your project and establish authentication between your host and docker registry :

```
gcloud init
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Step5: pull image on that instance:

```
docker pull gcr.io/<project_id>/<image>:<tag>
```

Step6: run image using docker

```
docker run -itd <image-name> /bin/bash
```

Step7: If everything goes right then you will find your container in `docker ps` otherwise you can check your container in `docker ps -a`